# Firefox strange right click event bubbling behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm experiencing a strange issue in firefox where the click event is raised on the document node when right-clicking a child node.

This code illustrates the issue: http://jsfiddle.net/RyDZU/5/

Updated version : http://jsfiddle.net/RyDZU/10/

```
$(document).on("click","span",function(e) {
    console.log('span');
    console.log(e.isPropagationStopped());
});

$(document).on("click","div",function(e) {
    console.log('div');
    console.log(e.isPropagationStopped());
    e.stopPropagation();
    console.log(e.isPropagationStopped());
});

$(document).on("click",function(e) {
    console.log('body');
    console.log(e.isPropagationStopped());
});
```

HTML:
    <div><span>Test</span></div>

If you right-click the word "test" the word "body" is printed in the console on firefox (21). Not in IE 10 / Chrome.

How can i prevent this event from being raised in Firefox?

This does not work:

```
$("body").on("click", "span", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: There is a bug logged for this: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=184051. I guess you have to detect which mouse button was clicked and cancel it if right mouse or middle mouse was clicked on Firefox.

Comment: @Mr.DucNguyen wow, this bug dates back to _2002?!_

Comment: Yes, and it's still active :), it might be "fixed" in another decade, but I doubt it since we've already come to "touch" event era

Answer (score 1):

I'm running into the same issue. I have a fiddle where if you left click in the green square the event is handled by both handler2 (on the div) and handler3 (on document). However if you right click, only handler3 is called, which means there isn't an easy way to stop propagation on right clicks in the div.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wrPh9/4/)

```
// requisite jsfiddle code snippet
function handler2() {
    console.log('in handler2');
}

function handler3() {
    console.log('in handler3');
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#block2').on('click', handler2);
    $(document).on('click', handler3);
});
```

I also tried playing around with the settings dom.event.contextmenu.enabled and services.sync.prefs.sync.dom.event.contextmenu.enabled, but they had no effect on this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed by using [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) to check which mouse button was pressed (from the event listener attached to the document). See https://stackoverflow.com/a/12430795/1170489.

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
$(document).on("click",function(e) {
    console.log('body');
    console.log(e.isPropagationStopped());
});
```

the first handler in your script. When you do it your way, the document click handler is hiding the span and div handlers.

Comment: Nope, same issue. The event handler fires on right click. http://jsfiddle.net/RyDZU/6/